# VBS (MSGBOX)- How can I add multiple attribute numbers (such as 16)

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a VBS script that has a message box with multiple numerical attributes,

for example having a message box with the  *16 icon*  as well as the *2  value*  (Abort,Retry,Ignore)

In other words, I would want to combine the following two scripts into one.

```
    lol=msgbox("Body message",16,"Title")
```

with

```
    lol=msgbox("Body message",2,"Title")
```

How do I get to combine these two attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the numbers together:

```
lol=msgbox("Body message",18,"Title")
```

Comment: It's that simple? Wow.